# How to reinstantaite Object arrays in implemented class of Interfaces?

Tags: java, inheritance, static

I have a Interface I which has a static function returnbjectsCreated()

Initially class A and B implemented I

But I want to keep track of the objects created.

So I created a class C that implements I ; A and B extends C 
I thought of appending the array in defObj[] in the constructor of C but didn't work as it was final.

```
    public interface I
    {
        DefObj[] defObj;

     public static DefObj[] returnCreatedObjArr()
    {
    return defObj;
    }
  }
```

Each time I create a new object for A or B, it needs to be appended to defObj in the interface.

i.e when I access I.returnCreatedObjArr() it should return all objects created.

What should I do ?

Note: No external packages or java collections  can be used

Can you please add a snippet of that? The trouble I am facing right now is as follows :

```
private Node[] updateDefObj()
    {
        DefObj[] new DefObj = new DefObj[defObj.length + 1];
        System.arraycopy(defObj.length, 0, new defObj.length, 0, defObj.length);
        defObj.[defObj.length+1] = this;
        return defObj.length;
    }

class constructor:
     C() {

        defObj = new DefObj.length[defObj.length + 1] ;
        defObj = updateDefObj(defObj);  }
```

Comment: Use an ArrayList.

Comment: But I am not allowed to use any collections

Comment: Then you'll have to keep creating new arrays as it grows in size. Which is what ArrayList does under the hood.

Comment: Can you please add a snippet of that? The trouble I am facing right now is as follows :


private Node[] updateDefObj()
    {
        DefObj[] new DefObj = new DefObj[defObj.length + 1];
        System.arraycopy(defObj.length, 0, new defObj.length, 0, defObj.length);
        defObj.[defObj.length+1] = this;
        return defObj.length;
    }


     C() {

        defObj = new DefObj.length[defObj.length + 1] ;

Comment: You can find ArrayList's implementation here: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l442

Comment: Turn `DefObj` into a linked list by adding a reference to `next`. Maintain references to the head and tail of the list. Update the tail, return the head.

Comment: @shmosel. That's pretty cool. I traced that as far as `grow`, wondering the whole time when I'd hit the native method, but nope, all Java.

Comment: You can't reassign `defObj` because any field in an interface is automatically `public static final`. Putting such static stuff in an interface is bad design as it doesn't define an interface for a class. Put it in a shared superclass if you need it - you'll need it in any case as an interface has no control over object instantiation and a superclass has, as you've discovered.

Comment: @MadPhysicist It eventually calls `System.arraycopy()`, which is a native method. Though it's not strictly necessary either.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper class of Array (for my example MyInterfaceObjectArray) which will increment its size on the runtime. You can implement the increment logic as you wish, in my case, I have double the current size of Array also it starts from size 10. You can try like below:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        MyInterfaceImpl impl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            new MyInterfaceImpl();
        }
        System.out.println("Object Array : " + Arrays.toString(MyInterface.getObjects()));
    }
}

class MyInterfaceObjectArray {
    MyInterface[] objects;
    private int offset = 0;

    MyInterfaceObjectArray() {
        objects = new MyInterface[10];
    }

    public void addObjectToArray(MyInterface i) {
        if (offset == objects.length) {
            MyInterface[] copyObjects = new MyInterface[offset * 2];
            System.arraycopy(objects, 0, copyObjects, 0, offset - 1);
            objects = copyObjects;
        }
        objects[offset] = i;
        offset++;
    }

    public MyInterface[] getObjects() {
        return objects;
    }

}

interface MyInterface {
    MyInterfaceObjectArray interfaceObjectArray = new MyInterfaceObjectArray();

    static MyInterface[] getObjects() {
        return interfaceObjectArray.getObjects();
    }
}

class MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface {
    MyInterfaceImpl() {
        interfaceObjectArray.addObjectToArray(this);
    }
}
```